# Return additional fields with elastic search term aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to return back `id` and `label` from an aggregation query, but don't know how.

```json
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "other_attribute": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "clients": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "label": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example from a document:

```json
    "clients": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Frankreich"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Niederlande"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Deutschland"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "label": "Vereinigtes Königreich"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "label": "Österreich"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "label": "Schweiz"
      }
    ],
```

My aggregation query (part) so far is:

[image: Aggregation query]

Which brings back a proper aggregation "by id":

[image: Response]

But what I need is also the `label` of the client in this example.

Is it possible to simple get back "additional fields" with this particular aggregation (without or with changing the mapping)

Trying a top hit aggregation returns "all" clients, but I only need the one related to the bucket.

[image: top hit]
[image: top hit result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [nested field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), to achieve your use case

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "clients": {
        "type": "nested",       // note this
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "label": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "uniqueId": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "clients"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "xterm": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "clients.id",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "xsource": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": [
                  "clients.label"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The search result will be

```
"aggregations": {
    "uniqueId": {
      "doc_count": 6,
      "xterm": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 1,                     // note this
            "doc_count": 1,
            "xsource": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "66086446",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "clients",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "label": "Frankreich"         // note this
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 2,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "xsource": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "66086446",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "clients",
                      "offset": 1
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "label": "Niederlande"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 3,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "xsource": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "66086446",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "clients",
                      "offset": 2
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "label": "Deutschland"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 4,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "xsource": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "66086446",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "clients",
                      "offset": 3
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "label": "Vereinigtes Königreich"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 7,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "xsource": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "66086446",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "clients",
                      "offset": 4
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "label": "Österreich"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 8,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "xsource": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "66086446",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "clients",
                      "offset": 5
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "label": "Schweiz"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```